# Mongodb Update document, convert string of time milliseconds to ISODate of any time zone

Tags: mongodb, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to convert this document:

```
   { "_id" : 1, "date" : "1441806397596" }
```

to UTC-03:00 Date.

I'm already tried this:

```
 db.document.update({_id:1},{date:ISODate(this.date)})
```

but converts to UTC-00:00 time zone.

But I think I'm missing a time zone parameter or something to convert the time zone as well.

How Can I convert correctly to any time zone? in my case to UTC-03:00

Comment: All BSON dates are stored in UTC; any time zone conversions need to happen outside of the database, in the code that displays the date to the user.

Comment: I need to convert to another time zone cos, I will do a ETL to another database afterwords. @JohnnyHK

Comment: Then you would do the conversion in your ETL process.  Not in MongoDB.